# What does 'evaluated by judge' mean?

Tags: terminology, pokemon-x-y

In Pokemon X and Y online battles, sometimes it will show statistics on the side of the battle for each player. Sometimes though, one will pop up that says "Times evaluated by judge." What does this mean exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Times evaluated by judge" refers to how many times you've had a Pokemon's stats evaluated by the [stats judge](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Stats_judge#In_Generation_VI) in Kiloude City (Battle Resort for OR/AS). It is a relatively meaningless statistic, though it could be an indicator of how much effort each trainer put into their teams - breeding and checking for perfect IVs.